# Where is my PHP OOP wrong?

Tags: php, html, oop

Hey I'm new to OO in PHP but I know basic Java and understand OO in Java but I'm trying to understand how to make it properly intertwine with HTML via OO.  Why wouldn't the code below spit back the message?  Thanks.

```
<?php

class SubmitPost {

    public function __construct() {
        $Db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Comment', 'root', '');
    }

    public function Comment($Post, $Time, $Title) {

        $Post = strip_tags($_POST['Post']);
        $Time = time();
        $Title = strip_tags($_POST['Title']);

            $Messages = array('success' => 'Your comment has been added.', 'error' => 'There was a problem adding your comment.');

                if(isset($Post, $Title)) {
                    return $Messages['success'];
                } else {
                    return $Messages['error'];
                }

    }
}

$New = new SubmitPost;
var_dump($New);
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="OO.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Your Title"><br />
            <textarea placeholder="Your Comment" name="Post"></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Comment">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not executing the `Comment` function, just the constructor. Also it doesn't seem you need the arguments.

Comment: Check if the request type is post, then run `$New->Comment()`. (All the parameters aren't used anyway, they're set within the function.)

Comment: A class without any properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your method somewhere.

```
$New = new SubmitPost();
echo $New->Comment("needless","because","unused");  // You are not using these values in your method
//var_dump($New);
```

**Edit**
That's not really OOP. It should be something like

```
public function Comment($Post, $Time, $Title) {
    $Post = strip_tags($Post);
    $Title = strip_tags($Title);
   //....
   }
```

and call it like

```
$New = new SubmitPost();
echo $New->Comment($_POST["Post"],time(),$_POST["Title"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object does not have anything in it. That is why you are not getting any output. Try the following code:

```
<?php

class SubmitPost {
    public $test;
    public function __construct() {
        $Db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=comment', 'root', '');
        $this->test = "yahoo";
    }

    public function Comment($Post, $Time, $Title) {

        $Post = strip_tags($_POST['Post']);
        $Time = time();
        $Title = strip_tags($_POST['Title']);

            $Messages = array('success' => 'Your comment has been added.', 'error' => 'There was a problem adding your comment.');

                if(isset($Post, $Title)) {
                    return $Messages['success'];
                } else {
                    return $Messages['error'];
                }

    }
}

$New = new SubmitPost;
var_dump($New);
```

Comment: @John: Follow the Hanky 웃 Panky's reply.